# How to copy files off Ubuntu Touch on Nexus 4 with broken screen?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, touchscreen, adb, copy

I have Ubuntu Touch installed on my Nexus 4. I recently dropped the phone cracking the touchscreen. The screen no longer responds to touch. The three buttons work. I can turn the device on and off, start the bootloader and navigate through it.

I would like to copy my pictures off the phone. I've tried using adb but it says error:device not found.

Is there anything I can do to copy files off the phone without the touchscreen?

(Not sure this will be relevant but I have a new nexus 4 with a bad battery. I plan to move the battery from the broken phone into the new one. Maybe I could move the memory storage to the new phone as well?)

Comment: When I attach my Android phone, a Files session opens at `mtp://[usb:002,006]/` (depending on the hub and port). From what you say, this does not happen for you. Does anything happen?

Comment: When I plug the phone in nothing happens. Not sure how to check for a session at mtp://[usb:002,006]/.

Comment: Try `lsusb` and see what it says. On my machine with my Samsung phone and memory stick it says [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/13854915/).

Comment: Don't have the phone with me at the moment but I did lsusb previously and there were no entries for the phone. I can get the exact output later if its helpful. Also other usb devices do work fine.